# Apache Tomcat does not contain conf/Catalina/localhost

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, netbeans

I have just installed netbeans in Linux RHEL6.
I have to create xml file for my Java application in conf/Catalina/localhost/something.xml

The problem is, there are two tomcats. 
First one is the one which is used as CATALINA_BASE in /home/../.netbeans/7.3.1/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base the one contains Catalina/localhost in conf folder. But if I insert something.xml in that directory, nothing will happen.
So, I must insert something.xml in second tomcat /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.34 the CATALINA_HOME. But I cannot find Cataline/localhost in conf directory. I have tried to start tomcat manually using ./startup.sh and from netbeans, but still the Catalina/localhost cannot be found in that directory.

How to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try creating the directory explicitly using mkdir?

Comment: I have tried that in conf directory and I got no result

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to create something.xml in correct location then all you should do is this.

- In Netbeans search for context.xml in your project.
- Add your data there. When you will deploy your project a file will be automatically generated with your {projectname}.xml and will be dropped in correct conf folder

Comment: I am using jar library and the xml file name have to be the library name and placed in conf/Catalina/localhost/libraryname.xml.
Can it be done with context.xml?

Comment: Not sure... But have you tried looking for your tomcat path by clicking on services->tomcat X.X->Properties?